ValueError: expected sequence of length 32128 at dim 3 (got 512)
I tried to train the following model but I keep receiving the mentioned issue:
import pandas as pd
import torch
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau
from torch.nn.utils.clip_grad import clip_grad_norm_
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
import numpy as np
import os
import random

# Set the seed for reproducibility
seed = 42
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)


# Load the datasets
# IMPORT REQUIRED DATASET
path = "/content/train_set.csv"
path_val = "/content/dev_set.csv"
path_test = "/content/test_ur.csv"

ds_train = pd.read_csv(path)
ds_val = pd.read_csv(path_val)
ds_test = pd.read_csv(path_test)
ds_train

ds_train=ds_train.dropna()
ds_val=ds_val.dropna()
ds_test=ds_test.dropna()


train_df = ds_train
val_df = ds_val
test_df = ds_test


# Create a custom dataset class
class UrduEnglishDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df, tokenizer, max_source_length, max_target_length):
        self.df = df
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_source_length = max_source_length
        self.max_target_length = max_target_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        urdu_text = self.df.iloc[idx, 0]
        english_text = self.df.iloc[idx, 1]

        encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            urdu_text,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=self.max_source_length,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )

        labels = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            english_text,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=self.max_target_length,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )

        return {
            'input_ids': encoding['input_ids'].flatten(),
            'attention_mask': encoding['attention_mask'].flatten(),
            'labels': labels['input_ids'].flatten(),
            'labels_attention_mask': labels['attention_mask'].flatten()
        }

# Set the model parameters
model_params = {
    "MODEL": "t5-small",
    "TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE": 2,# 4, # 8,
    "VALID_BATCH_SIZE":1, #1 2, #4,
    "TRAIN_EPOCHS": 5, ##3
    "VAL_EPOCHS": 1,
    "LEARNING_RATE": 1e-4,
    "MAX_SOURCE_TEXT_LENGTH": 64, #128, #256, # 512,
    "MAX_TARGET_TEXT_LENGTH": 64, #128, #/ 256, # 512,
    "SEED": 42,
    "GRAD_CLIP": 1.0,
    "PATIENCE": 5
}

# Set the device (TPU or GPU)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Load the tokenizer
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_params["MODEL"])

# Create the datasets and data loaders
train_dataset = UrduEnglishDataset(train_df, tokenizer, model_params["MAX_SOURCE_TEXT_LENGTH"], model_params["MAX_TARGET_TEXT_LENGTH"])
val_dataset = UrduEnglishDataset(val_df, tokenizer, model_params["MAX_SOURCE_TEXT_LENGTH"], model_params["MAX_TARGET_TEXT_LENGTH"])
test_dataset = UrduEnglishDataset(test_df, tokenizer, model_params["MAX_SOURCE_TEXT_LENGTH"], model_params["MAX_TARGET_TEXT_LENGTH"])

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=model_params["TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE"], shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=model_params["VALID_BATCH_SIZE"], shuffle=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=model_params["VALID_BATCH_SIZE"], shuffle=False)

# Load the model
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_params["MODEL"])

# Set the training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='results_t5small',
    num_train_epochs=model_params["TRAIN_EPOCHS"],
    per_device_train_batch_size=model_params["TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE"],
    per_device_eval_batch_size=model_params["VALID_BATCH_SIZE"],
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='logs',
    logging_steps=10,
    eval_strategy='steps',
    save_steps=500,
    eval_steps=500,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    save_total_limit=5,
    report_to='tensorboard',
    learning_rate=model_params["LEARNING_RATE"],
    fp16=True
)
def compute_metrics(pred, label_ids=None):
    # Convert the label_ids to a tensor
    label_ids = label_ids if label_ids is not None else torch.tensor(pred.label_ids)

    # Convert the predictions to a tensor
    predictions = torch.tensor(pred.predictions)

    # Ensure the predictions tensor has the expected sequence length
    if predictions.size(3) != model_params["MAX_TARGET_TEXT_LENGTH"]:
        # Reshape the predictions tensor to match the expected length
        predictions = predictions.reshape(predictions.size(0), predictions.size(1), model_params["MAX_TARGET_TEXT_LENGTH"])

    # Compute the accuracy
    accuracy = torch.sum(label_ids == predictions.argmax(-1)).item()

    # Return the accuracy
    return {"accuracy": accuracy}
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics #*lambda pred: {"accuracy": torch.sum(pred.label_ids == pred.predictions.argmax(-1)).item()}
)

# Train the model
history = trainer.train()


Any suggestions, I receive the following error:/
Here's the full error message
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-68426953da61> in <cell line: 58>()
     56 
     57 # Train the model
---> 58 history = trainer.train()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1883                 hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()
   1884         else:
-> 1885             return inner_training_loop(
   1886                 args=args,
   1887                 resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   2289                     self.control = self.callback_handler.on_step_end(args, self.state, self.control)
   2290 
-> 2291                     self._maybe_log_save_evaluate(tr_loss, grad_norm, model, trial, epoch, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   2292                 else:
   2293                     self.control = self.callback_handler.on_substep_end(args, self.state, self.control)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in _maybe_log_save_evaluate(self, tr_loss, grad_norm, model, trial, epoch, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   2719         metrics = None
   2720         if self.control.should_evaluate:
-> 2721             metrics = self.evaluate(ignore_keys=ignore_keys_for_eval)
   2722             self._report_to_hp_search(trial, self.state.global_step, metrics)
   2723 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in evaluate(self, eval_dataset, ignore_keys, metric_key_prefix)
   3570 
   3571         eval_loop = self.prediction_loop if self.args.use_legacy_prediction_loop else self.evaluation_loop
-> 3572         output = eval_loop(
   3573             eval_dataloader,
   3574             description="Evaluation",

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in evaluation_loop(self, dataloader, description, prediction_loss_only, ignore_keys, metric_key_prefix)
   3852                 )
   3853             else:
-> 3854                 metrics = self.compute_metrics(EvalPrediction(predictions=all_preds, label_ids=all_labels))
   3855         elif metrics is None:
   3856             metrics = {}

<ipython-input-6-68426953da61> in compute_metrics(pred, label_ids)
     35 
     36     # Convert the predictions to a tensor
---> 37     predictions = torch.tensor(pred.predictions)
     38 
     39     # Ensure the predictions tensor has the expected sequence length

ValueError: expected sequence of length 32128 at dim 3 (got 512)


PS: Please consider that I changed the model_params["MAX_TARGET_TEXT_LENGTH"] = 32128 just to check and it does not work because the session stops.
.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

@furas check it now! I added the full error message.
